# unity netcode for gameobjects client not connecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can someone help me out I keep trying to connect my client to and host but unity keeps sending me this error message

> Netcode] Deferred messages were received for a trigger of type OnSpawn with key 2, but that trigger was not received within within 1 second(s).
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
> Unity.Netcode.NetworkLog:LogWarning (string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Runtime/Logging/NetworkLog.cs:28)
> Unity.Netcode.DeferredMessageManager:PurgeTrigger (Unity.Netcode.IDeferredMessageManager/TriggerType,ulong,Unity.Netcode.DeferredMessageManager/TriggerInfo) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Runtim

Answer (score 0):

In my case  I forgot to implement `INetworkSerializable` in my structs. Once I did that, everything worked out all right:

```
private struct ToolInfo : INetworkSerializable
{
    public Quaternion rot;
    public Vector3 pos;
    public Item.ItemInfo item;

    public void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter
    {
        if (serializer.IsReader)
        {
            var reader = serializer.GetFastBufferReader();
            reader.ReadValueSafe(out rot);
            reader.ReadValueSafe(out pos);
            reader.ReadValueSafe(out item);
        }
        else
        {
            var writer = serializer.GetFastBufferWriter();
            writer.WriteValueSafe(rot);
            writer.WriteValueSafe(pos);
            writer.WriteValueSafe(item);
        }
    }
}
```